# Windows and Python: can't import Keras module

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, keras, python-import

***Environment***

> Python: 3.7.6
>
> Tensorflow: 2.1.0
>
> Keras: 2.3.1
>
> Anaconda: anaconda3
>
> OS: Windows 10 x64

I have installed **tensorflow** and **keras** using **pip** on my Windows pc.
The installation went fine and importing **tensorflow** too, but I have a problem importing **keras**.

I've read that tensorflow and keras sometimes confilct each other, but I don't know if this is my case.

*Update: when I use tensorflow like "tf.constant = (2.0, name="const")" it gives me error, a similiar error to the keras error written below.*

Can someone help me with a *list of steps* to follow to get a working keras and tensorflow module?

This is the error after "*import keras*" :

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-88d96843a926>", line 1, in <module>
    import keras
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .load_backend import epsilon
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py", line 90, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\user\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Looks like there is some issue with the tensorflow backend when you installed. Did you install in local or Virtual environment? Are you able to run a simple tensorflow code without any issues? Can you try import tensorflow as tf?

Comment: I installed tensorflow in local environment.Yes I'm able to import tensorflow without any issues: import tensorflow as tf works.Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: Update: I can " import tensorflow as tf " but when I use it like " const = tf.constant(2.0, name="const") " it gives me error, a similiar error similiar to Keras importing error.

Comment: Looks like tensorflow was not installed correctly with all the components. Did you build TF from source or did you use pip binaries ( as pip3 install tensorflow*). I think reinstalling tensorflow should work. Another thing is you don't need to explicitly install keras. You can use keras under tensorflow as in `from tensorflow import keras`

Comment: Now I tried installing tensorflow with "pip3 install tensorflow", but I now "import tensorflow as tf" doesn't work too. Should I use other ways to install it ?

Comment: Did you follow instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install). Were you able to install tensorflow successfully?

Comment: Yes
"pip install --upgrade pip" and 
"pip install tensorflow"

Comment: When I install tensorflow it gives me "Requirement already satisfied: ...", Should I have to unistall before ?

Comment: first uninstall, keras and tensorflow, then restart computer, then pip install tensorflow==2.1. If you still have problem then try `conda update --all`. there are lot of solution in [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/275390).

Comment: I solved using "conda install tensorflow" and "conda install keras"